# SQL Multiple Statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I am using php and mysql to update rows in my DB.  I have 4 update statements in a row, yet only the last one works.  I have confirmed that the statements work if they are used alone, but when I have them executed one after another only the last one executed works.  I am receiving no error messages.  Any help? Thanks!

```
$sql = "UPDATE comlog SET name='$name1', message='$message1' WHERE id=1";
$sql = "UPDATE comlog SET name='$name2', message='$message2' WHERE id=2";
$sql = "UPDATE comlog SET name='$name3', message='$message3' WHERE id=3";
$sql = "UPDATE comlog SET name='$name', message='$message' WHERE id=4";
```

In the above code, only the row with id 4 is being updated.

Comment: Need to see the full code you're using to execute these statements.

Comment: Do you actually have rows with these `id`s?

Comment: Where is the code that actually executes the statement in the variable "$sql" ? Because it seems like you are just overriding the variable with a new statement before executing :P (i.e. if you execute after the code block in your question, then the last value is the "id=4" one)

Comment: If you wanna update 4 times with the $mysql statement, I believe you should just initialize them as different variables and execute the commands individually. Or you can create a for loop and increment your variables by 1 each time it runs along with your execute command.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple.

You are declaring the same variable for EACH sql string.

You need to declare it something like:

```
$sql1 = "";
$sql2 = "";
$sql3 = "";
$sql4 = "";
```